# Rules for valid password

Tags: feature-request

I wanted to set up a StackExchange openID. But it insists on a password that contains 3 from the 4: lowercase, uppercase, special character and numeral. I have only two passwords across multiple sites. I always forget passwords with special rules. Out of a few services which insists on this, I only use Delicious. But I had to click the "forgot password?" the first few weeks.

I decided to stick to Google as the ID provider as I would not forget that password. Please remove the rule

Comment: Is one of your passwords `password`?

Comment: Use a password manager like LastPass to generate & manage passwords

Comment: Phrases in another language, can deter over-shoulder snooping (and dictionaries)   :-)

Comment: I've never wanted 125 rep on meta more than I do right now, just so I could vote this down. Absolutely terrible idea.

Comment: @PengOne: No, but `hunter2`. ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I decided to stick to Google as the ID provider as I would not forget that password.

Excellent compromise. Google is a fine provider. I wish you happiness in your future adventures together.

Comment: excellent. I will do the same

Answer (score 0):

I agree - why can't someone use a passphrase?

How insecure is this password: my password is all lowercase

Comment: I'd say it's pretty insecure. It is definitely lacking in self-confidence. Now, "MY PASSWORD IS ALL UPPERCASE", that's a password that just exudes confidence - no insecurity there.

Comment: @charles - touché (i think)

Comment: Better still: "MY PASSWORD IS ALL LOWERCASE" Really, who would suspect it?

Comment: Personally, I go with "This is not my password." That way any machine that tries to break my password will itself be broken.